# How to install "qrspy" package in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, request, qliksense

I'm trying to connect Qlik Sense API using Python. I want to control the Qlik Sense App using Python & perform some operations. I searched for it & did found some relevant stuff,

- https://github.com/clintcarr/qrspy
- https://clintcarr.github.io/qrspy/#welcome-to-qrspy

I found that "qrspy" package is required, 
I tried to installed it using,

`pip install qrspy`

I also tried using conda

`conda install qrspy`

but showing error

**ERROR**:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement QRSpy (from versions:
>   )
>   No matching distribution found for QRSpy

Can someone please help me how to import it or tell me any other way to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

Since the repository does not include a `setup.py`, I think the packages is not available via pip and you need to get this package by downloading the files into your project or another place in your python path. If I see everything correctly, you need only the file `qrspy.py`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sparky05. I'll look out for it.